# como obtener los valores de un array

Tags: php

que tal necesito obtener los atributos de un array, hice una solicitud POST que me trae un array de objetos, los trae correctamente, pero no puedo obtener un dato en la variable $folio->documentos->correlativo;

```
$datadecode = json_decode($result, false);
 $folio = $datadecode;
 return $folio;
```

\Core\SysLogger::info(**CLASS**, 'FOLIO VARIABLE'.var_export($folio,
true));

```
[Fri Nov 25 12:41:12.9849 2022][Resolucion\CrearModelo:info][pid 
 12][client:172.21.0.1][localhost:80][index.php? 
 mid=\Resolucion\Crear][UID:638] 
 [PHPSESSID:8kc8cekg56p9mi1nqdkga4mse3] IndapSysLo
  gger: FOLIO VARIABLE stdClass::__set_state(array( 'mensaje' => 
 'id documentos creado(s) con éxito', 'success' => true, 
  'documentos' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'id_doc1' => 
  '23871208', 'id
  _doc2' => NULL, 'correlativo' => '0935-1704/2022', )), ))
```

Aqui recibo los datos y desempaqueto la respuesta

```
$folio_generado = $this->modelo->generarFolio($tramite[0], $tramite[1]);
              linea 567  $datos_resolucion[$i]['folio']  = $folio_generado->documentos- 
 >correlativo;
```

El error al extraer los datos

```
[Fri Nov 25 15:41:12.985510 2022] [:error] [pid 12] [client 172.21.0.1:51048] PHP 
Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in 
/var/www/html/subsystem/Resolucion/modulos/Crear/Crear.php on
line 567, referer: http://localhost/?mid=\\Resolucion\\Crear
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa. ¿Con qué variable tienes problema? Haz un `var_dump($tuVariableConProblemas);` y dinos qué muestra pulsando en [edit].

Comment: modifique la pregunta

Comment: No se entiende dónde exactamente es el problema, ni nos dices qué muestra la prueba que te sugerí, haciendo `var_dump` de la variable problemática.

Comment: linea 567 al final esta el mensaje de error

Comment: Te sugiero replantear tu pregunta, imprimir las variables de resultado y su estructura.

Comment: Segun el error esto no devuelve un objeto: `$this->modelo->generarFolio($tramite[0], $tramite[1]);`  y como tampoco sabemos lo que es `$tramite` ni `generarFolio` poco podemos ayudarte de momento.  Suerte!